# How to edit multiple titles of sections in UITableViews?

Tags: ios, uitableview

My `UITableView` contains multiple `sections` and I would like these `sections` to have different names. The `titleForHeaderInSection` method is provided to change the name of a `section`. It returns a `String` and it looks like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "My First Section"
}
```

This is great for changing one name, but what if I have multiple `sections`? Should I use more than one functions? Should I declare the names in some ways in the `viewDidLoad` or `numberOfSectionsInTableView` methods? They don't like the right choices, though.

How to edit multiple titles of `sections` in `UITableViews`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array of your `section` titles, return the correct string like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let sectionInfo = arrayOfSectionNames[section]
    return sectionInfo 
}
```

Comment: The wording of your answer doesn't match your solution code. The value you're returning isn't an array, it's an optional string.